# Remote Debug Weblogic Clustered Servers

Tags: weblogic

I have a java application which is currently deployed in weblogic clustered environment with 2 managed servers. Would like to enable remote debugging for me to investigate further the issue on session data replication. I followed the steps provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237033/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-on-weblogic-clustered-environment). After restarting the 2 managed servers, it seems the configuration has no effect. I used the same debug config below in my 2 managed servers.

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8457,server=y,suspend=n
```

I also tried adding the below line on each managed server startup script.

```
export debugFlag=true  
export DEBUG_PORT=8457
```

I use telnet command and got this error: **Could not open connection to the host, on port 8457: Connect failed.**

Linux firewall is already disabled.

Has anyone already encountered this issue? In addition, how to use it for me to enable debug in my IDE (e.g. Eclipse/IntelliJ)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How are you setting these parameters? are they on the admin console, and use Node Manager to start up them?

Comment: @devwebcl, thanks for the prompt response. I tried to set it via Server Start tab on each managed server in the weblogic admin console as describe in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237033/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-on-weblogic-clustered-environment. And I started both using Node Manager and then using startManagedWebLogic.sh. And the behaviour is still the same. Unable to connect the debug port.

Comment: startManagedWebLogic.sh is different way to start your managed servers. Maybe you can try to set those properties in that script file.

Comment: Hi @devwebcl, it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is already resolved. As advised by @devwebcl, I put the additional script below in my startManagedWebLogic.sh

**export JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8457,server=y,suspend=n"**

I put the same argument (e.g. *-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8457,server=y,suspend=n*) in the Server Start argument section on each managed server in weblogic admin console.

It will make sure that either you start your managed server via weblogic admin console or via shell startup script of each managed server, the same argument will be picked up.